# How can I retrieve selected files from vuefinder for my online editor in Laravel-Vue?

Tags: laravel, vuejs3

I'm trying to use Vuefinder (https://github.com/n1crack/vuefinder) as a file explorer in my Laravel-Vue custom page builder. According to the documentation, I should be able to emit a select event and retrieve the selected files for online editors like TinyMCE/CKEditor. However, when I use the following code:
`<vue-finder id='my_vuefinder' url="/files" @select="alert('selected')"></vue-finder>`
It doesn't seem to work - nothing happens when I select a file. I've tried looking through the source code to find where the select event is emitted, but I can't seem to find it anywhere.

I did notice that in vuefinder/src/components/Statusbar.vue, the vf-nodes-selected event is used to set the number of selected items, like this:
`emitter.on('vf-nodes-selected', (items) => { selectedItemCount.value = items.length; })`

I'm not sure if there's a similar approach I can use to access the selected items data. Can anyone help me figure out what's going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

[image]

The library is updated recently, it has an example now.